# having trouble Integrating griffon project in to eclipse and ant

Tags: eclipse, groovy, griffon

I have successfully integrated and imported a griffon project (ant based) into eclipse. I have also added `griffon_home` and `user_home` variables to classpath of eclipse. Now i am getting error trace in markers tab.

```
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/biz.aQute/bndlib/jars/bndlib-1.50.0.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/com.h2database/h2/jars/h2-1.3.164.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/com.jcraft/jsch/jars/jsch-0.1.48.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/com.jcraft/jzlib/jars/jzlib-1.1.1.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/com.miglayout/miglayout-core/jars/miglayout-core-4.2.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/com.miglayout/miglayout-swing/jars/miglayout-swing-4.2.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.6.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/jars/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/commons-pool/commons-pool/jars/commons-pool-1.5.6.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/jline/jline/jars/jline-0.9.94.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/junit/junit/jars/junit-4.11.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/net.java.dev.glazedlists/glazedlists_java15/jars/glazedlists_java15-1.8.0.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.ezmorph/ezmorph/jars/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/jars/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.ant/ant-junit/jars/ant-junit-1.9.3.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.ant/ant-launcher/jars/ant-launcher-1.9.3.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.ant/ant/jars/ant-1.9.3.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.1.2.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.1.2.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-actions-runtime/jars/griffon-actions-runtime-0.3.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-datasource-runtime/jars/griffon-datasource-runtime-0.3.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-glazedlists-runtime/jars/griffon-glazedlists-runtime-0.9.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-gsql-runtime/jars/griffon-gsql-runtime-0.9.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-i18n-support-runtime/jars/griffon-i18n-support-runtime-0.1.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-miglayout-runtime/jars/griffon-miglayout-runtime-0.4.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-swing-compile/jars/griffon-swing-compile-1.3.0.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/griffon-swing-runtime/jars/griffon-swing-runtime-1.3.0.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon/griffon-cli/jars/griffon-cli-1.5.0.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon/griffon-rt/jars/griffon-rt-1.5.0.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon/griffon-scripts/jars/griffon-scripts-1.5.0.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/jars/http-builder-0.6.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.2.1.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/jars/jansi-1.9.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/jars/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar' in project 'addressbook'   addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-beans/jars/spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-context-support/jars/spring-context-support-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-context/jars/spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar' in project 'addressbook'    addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar' in project 'addressbook'  addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/xerces/xercesImpl/jars/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath variable: 'C:Users/Uday/.ivy2/cache/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/jars/xml-resolver-1.2.jar' in project 'addressbook' addressbook     Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    addressbook     Unknown Java Problem
No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.  build.xml   /addressbook    line 1  XML Problem
```

`griffon_home` D:\Griffon-1.5.0

`user_home` C:\users\Uday

Please suggest solution
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

found out what went wrong. when i integrated the project with **ANT** it created a build file in which **griffon.home** value is set to **${env.Griffon_home}** but the path was not being retrieved. i am not sure how to resolve it but for time being i replaced the value with **path to griffon home directory**.(i did add griffon_home to classpath in eclipse but of no use). now it is working fine.